# How can you compare an INT to many other INTs?

Tags: c#, compare, int

Well,

```
int a = 20;
int b = 30;
int c = 40;
int d = 50;

if (a > b,c,d)
```

how would i approach this, i have no idea i fail at every turn, its been hours

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is a short quantity of numbers, you can simply use the boolean logic:

```
if (a > b && a > c && a > d)
{
}
```

If you don't know in advance the quantity of numbers, what about creating a collection and compare the first number to the numbers from the collection through a loop?

```
var numbers = { 30, 40, 50 };
if (!numbers.Any(c => 20 <= c))
{
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put them in an array:

```
int a = 20;
int[] others = { 30, 40, 50 };

if(others.All(o => a > o))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: @Lester - Heh. I can type. Honestly.

Comment: the best part is i almost submitted my comment also saying `a > 0` :)

Answer (score 3):

Put them all in a list and do this:

```
if(list.All(x=> a > x))
```

Or in one line:

```
if(new List<int>{a, b, c, d}.All(x=> a > x))
```

**EDIT**
I changed the `Max()` to `All(x => a > x)` because the a > x will not return a true when `a == x` whereas Max() will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Non-LINQ example:

```
if (Math.Max(a, Math.Max(b, Math.Max(c, d))) == a)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is if the number x is greater than the other numbers, you could either compare them explicitly like `if(x>b & b>c)` or use something like `if(list.All(x=> a > x))`
 as mentioned above. If you have many numbers and all you want is the higher number, you could sort the list using a quick sort that could be efficient and get the first item.

It's a bit different if you need to compare them and get different comparissons then probably the easiest thing is to loop through the list.

Comment: You are right, i´m confusing algorithm names. I meant quicksort. You can use a different one, but many times quicksort will do fine. And many more times the language constructs will also be good enough.